# Is this a 1NF failure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, normalization

In considering a 1NF failure, no repeating groups of elements, what if you wanted to have a set limit on the number of a repeating group?

For example, you want a student to only have 3 phone numbers listed. No more. Would having a table as follows be considered a 1NF failure?

```
Student 1    Phone1    Phone2    Phone3
Sally        111-1111 222-2222   333-3333
John         555-5555 999-9999   NULL
```

You would be creating a limit. Is this acceptable, efficient database design?

Would it be better to put phone numbers in a separate table, as 1NF failures call for? How would you create the limit of 3 numbers per user if it were in separate table?

Comment: There is an excellent write-up @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not normalized.  You will have wasted space in your table when there are null values, and if you want to do things like search for a particular phone number, you'll have to search all three columns.  Instead use a separate table (StudentPhoneNumbers, for example) that stores them.  If you want to limit it to three, use a trigger to prevent more than three per student.

Comment: Not in 2NF or 3NF, but it **is** in 1NF, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Does SQL server support triggers?\

Comment: @user1122200 - Why are you asking about SQL Server? You have tagged MySQL?

Comment: @Oded has a great comment, but I think Jake offers valuable information here, whether it answers the exact question the OP asked or not.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's better than a single column with the values stored as a list.  Not saying much, though.  In any case - "Is this acceptable, efficient database design" - answer is a definite NO

Comment: I don't think this form is in 1NF. Mind you, this table would be populated with a multitude of other values. This is just a snippet of it.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server and MySQL both support triggers.

Comment: @user1122200 - Think it might depend on whose definition of 1NF you are using!

Comment: @Martin Smith: The standrad definition. No repeating elements or groups of elements.

Comment: @user1122200 - [Have you already read the Wiki section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_across_columns) which is basically exactly the same as your scenario?

Comment: Oded is correct, this is 1NF, in that there are not multiple values in a single column.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision - There is more to 1NF than just atomicity.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I appreciate your feedback but you seem to be criticizing the question as opposed to providing any valid information.

Comment: @MartinSmith: The Wiki section states that it is a violation of the *spirit* of 1NF, but does not state that it is indeed a 1NF failure.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Atomicity is barely a requirement of 1NF. 1NF shouldn't even be considered unless the table is already in atomic form.

Comment: @user1122200 - You seem to be being too sensitive. I haven't criticized the question anywhere.  If there are different definitions of 1NF in use (Codd vs Date) then that is surely relevant. You seem to have ignored the part where it says that if you use Date's definition it is a violation.

Comment: This certainly seems like a highly academic debate.  When it comes down to it, the answer is simply "Don't do this".  Why does it really matter if it is a bad idea at 1st or 2nd or 3rd NF?  It's still a bad idea.

Comment: @MikeB and thank goodness it's not the Youtube comments section

Comment: @Jake I do ask this question in regards to an academic viewpoint. Martin's wiki article does point out that a NULLable value would be a 1NF failure according to Date's definition of 1NF.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Duly noted. The wiki link I provided via comment to OP refreshing my memory.

Comment: I think that the table does not fail a strict normal form using the simple definitions of normal forms. However, it is of course inefficient, which is the problem and is arguably a failure of 1nf according to Date's definition, as noted by Martin Smith. Conclusively, to create a set limit of 3 in a normalized Phone Numbers Table, a trigger would be used as suggested by Jake Feasel.

Comment: @user - You could also manage this constraint declaratively by putting a unique constraint on `StudentId,Number` and a check constraint on `Number` enforcing it to be in the set `1,2,3`. Still not that easy to work with but because it is enforced by the RDBMS it can avoid exceeding the `3` limit due to race conditions in the trigger code. This requires a RDBMS that supports check constraints though. MySQL doesn't.

Comment: @Oded This is not 1nf. There are repeating groups of data (phone) and therefor it is 0nf.

Answer (score 6):

1NF bans repeating lists in a row.  Your design violates this, and so would the following design:

```
Student     Phones
'John D'    '555-5555, 666-6666, 777-7777'
'Sally S'   '111-1111, 222-2222'
```

The following design would violate 2NF, because the only primary key is `Name, Phone`, but the `Address` attribute does not depend on the `Phone`:

```
Name        Phone       Address
'John D'    '555-5555'  '1 Square Village'
'John D'    '666-6666'  '1 Square Village'
'John D'    '777-7777'  '1 Square Village'
'Sally S'   '111-1111'  '999 Flash City'
'Sally S'   '222-2222'  '999 Flash City'
```

The next design would violate 3NF, because AreaName does not depend on Name, but only on Area:

```
Name        Area    Phone   AreaName
'John D'    '555'   '5555'  '111name'
'John D'    '666'   '6666'  '666name'
'John D'    '777'   '7777'  '777name'
'Sally S'   '111'   '1111'  '111name'
'Sally S'   '222'   '2222'  '222name'
```

Even if your design violates 1NF, it's an excellent choice. The complexity of adding a `PhoneNumber` table is hardly ever justified.

Think about how hard an update to a customer becomes if you conform to 1NF.  The numbers would be in a separate table.  So if someone submits a form with an updated list of phone numbers, how would you change the database?  First you'd have to retrieve the existing list of numbers.  Then you'd have to compare them to the submitted list.  Then you'd have to delete or insert rows based on the difference.  One heck of a complex solution.

If you stick to your solution, you can just update the three columns.  The saved time can be spend on real features!  Or even writing long answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: lol. So it seems that a 1NF failure can occur even if there is a limit on the number of repeating groups, not just for repeating groups for where there is no set limit.

Comment: Actually, you'd just delete all his phone numbers and then insert all from the form - or you'd just make a separate form (ajax makes this nice) where you could delete single phone numbers and add new ones. So all in all it highly depends on your application what's more comfortable. Of course only unless you use an ORM where the separate table with proper relationships would give you an array for the user's phone numbers.

Comment: Correct.  Normal forms come from "Relational Algebra", for a good introduction see the [Stanford free class](http://www.db-class.org/).  I would say that normal form is a great tool, but you have to weigh the cost and benefit, and not apply it blindly.

Comment: @Andomar: What you stated as far as differences in *NF are correct, however I don't agree with the approach that modeling schema into *NF causes complexity which should be ignored, for the sake of releasing features. In the OP there are 3 phone fields, it is a reasonable assumption that he is providing a form for the data to be  provided by the user, so CRUD activity on a phone linking table is tolerable. In my experience it is far worse to forgo *NF. If his table consists of tens of thousands of records and he needs to run an alter to add another phone column, it will be painful.

Comment: It's a rare day when I've seen someone argue against normalization.  Ugh.

Answer (score 4):

Your relation variable (relvar) indeed violates 1NF but perhaps not for the reason you are expecting: it is the presence of the null that violates 1NF. If you think your relvar contains a repeating group, think again.

First normal form, or simply "normalized", is the minimum requirement for the relational model. To quote Chris Date:

> by definition, a null isn't a value. It follows that: A "type" that
>   contains a null isn't a type (because types contain values); A "tuple"
>   that contains a null isn't a tuple (because tuples contain values); A
>   "relation" that contains a null isn't a relation (because relations
>   contain tuples, and tuples don't contain nulls). In fact, nulls
>   violate the most fundamental relational principle of all—viz., The
>   Information Principle. The net of all this is that if nulls are
>   present, then we're certainly not talking about the relational model
>   (I don't know what we are talking about, but it's not the relational
>   model); the entire edifice crumbles, and all bets are off.

The point about repeating groups and 1NF is a tricky one to explain and I won't try. Instead, I urge you to read [Facts and Fallacies about First Normal Form](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=712), specifically the section "The ambiguity of Repeating Groups".

Assuming the null was eliminated, the relvar would satisfy 1NF but note we would need further information (e.g. keys) to determine whether it would also satisfy higher normal forms.

Comment: This relation does contain a repeating group, the Phone Number group. Simply put, that is clearly observable from the relation above. The presence of the NULL value makes it a 1NF violation even more so. The main focus here is the creation of a group of elements where a limited number is desired.

Comment: @user: I see three distinct attributes named `Phone1`, `Phone2` and `Phone3` respectively; they could have been named `home_phone`, `mobile_phone` and `work_phone`, the names are not significant, ditto their types. I see no "Phone Number group".

Comment: In a logical data model, if the data types in the columns in an entity are similar, they are by definition a repeating group. The same would apply to Hobby1, Hobby2, Hobby3 or Sport1, Sport2, Sport3.

Comment: Anyhow, we're just splitting hairs here. It matters according to the design of the database anyhow, but I got your point and I appreciate the Chris Date reference. He's got a lot to say about normal forms. Cheers.

Comment: "if the data types in the columns in an entity are similar, they are by definition a repeating group" -- Say an employees relvar has attributes for `birth_date` and `hire_date` both of type date: is that a repeating group? Of course not. Your definition of "repeating group" is incorrect. Read the `Facts and Fallacies` article again :) I don't disagree that it is a design issue but I don't agree it is a 1NF violation or a repeating group.

Comment: If I were defining those phone numbers as work_phone or home_phone, they would be independent... as a generic phone number, it certainly seems like it would be most efficient to separate them into another table. It's not just the type of data, like both birth_date and hire_date containing dates, that determines if it is a repeating group. It's also a logical determination. A person has to have both birth dates and hire dates but a person does not have to have a home_phone or work_phone.

Comment: It depends on the use of the data of course. 1NF failures apply to repeating groups and to repeating elements. We're again splitting hairs. Either way, it is clearly a 1NF failure.

Comment: @user: I don't think this is splitting hairs, 1NF is fairly fundamental :) Changing an attribute's name from `phone_2` to `work_phone` (or whatever) cannot alone cause a not first normal form (NFNF) relvar to satisfy 1NF. 1NF has a formal definition that  does not "depend on the use of the data." We can agree that your original design had design issues involving redundancy but it does not have a repeating group.

Answer (score 1):

user1122200, let's supose that your database design grows. And you need to assign certain data to each phone number (like phone location: 'house', 'work', ...). In this case you will longed a phone table. Also, supose that you need to find students from phone number (like pizza hut or taxis services when someone calls), it is more easy a query in a well normalized design that this query:

```
select *
from students
where 
  Phone1 = '91112223' or
  Phone2 = '91112223' or
  Phone3 = '91112223'
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would you create the limit of 3 numbers per user if it were in separate table?

I assume a student may have zero, one two or three phone numbers.

If your SQL product supported Full SQL-92:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
 student_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE StudentPhonebook
(
 student_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    REFERENCES Students (student_name), 
 phone_number CHAR(8) NOT NULL
    CHECK (phone_number LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), 
 UNIQUE (student_name, phone_number)
);

CREATE ASSERTION students_max_three_phone_numbers
   CHECK (
          NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                        FROM (
                              SELECT student_name, COUNT(*) AS tally
                                FROM StudentPhonebook
                               GROUP 
                                  BY student_name
                             ) AS DT1
                       WHERE tally > 3
                     )
         );
```

MySQL does not support `CHECK` of any flavour and no SQL product supports `CREATE ASSERTION` so the above constraints must presumably be written using procedural code e.g. triggers.

Out of interest, if your SQL product supported row-level `CHECK` constraints (as most do), one can use an `occurrence` attribute with a `BETWEEN 1 AND 3` constraint then include this attribute in a key constraint e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE StudentPhonebook
(
 student_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    REFERENCES Students (student_name), 
 phone_number CHAR(8) NOT NULL
    CHECK (phone_number LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), 
 occurrence INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
    CHECK (occurrence BETWEEN 1 AND 3), 
 UNIQUE (student_name, phone_number), 
 UNIQUE (student_name, occurrence)
);
```

Comment: In MySQL, the `CHECK (occurrence BETWEEN 1 AND 3)` constraint can be simulated with a `FOREIGN KEY` to a reference table with exactly 3 rows.